# xmonad help. Which is my Mod key?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm using this config file https://github.com/artificialbeing/xmonad-conf/blob/master/xmonad.hs

I've recompiled haskell by doing 
    xmonad --recompile

then I did M-q (where M is ALT) to restart xmonad.

There are no errors and I'm pretty sure the config is set up. However, ALT doesn't seem to be the mod key anymore. When I press ALT+SHIFT+RETURN, I don't get a new terminal screen.

Can someone help me figure out which key is mod?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant bit is `modMask = mod4Mask`; on most setups, mod 4 is the "Windows" key.

Comment: Alright I think you're right because when I do WIN+SHIFT+Q, it exits xmonad. However, WIN+SHIFT+RETURN is not opening the terminal. Could you help me out here?

Comment: It looks like you've got that key bound to run `urxvtc`. Have you installed your distribution's rxvt-unicode package? Is `urxvtc` on your path? Have you got the daemon `urxvtd` running that `urxvtc` is expecting to connect to?

Comment: I changed it to xterm but it still didn't work. When I run 'xterm' on my terminal, it launches, so it's obviously installed. I also tried 'gnome-terminal' which didn't work.

Comment: Your terminal's `$PATH` may differ from xmonad's. Be sure to set up (and export) that environment variable in `.xinitrc`. If that doesn't solve the problem, I recommend hopping on `#xmonad` to get a more interactive debugging experience.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple.Your new xmonad config does not specify a spawn Terminal action for the win+shift+Return key sequence. Add that line to kbMap. For syntax refer one of the configurations found here.http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The linked configuration _does_ have a binding for mod+shift+return: `((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_Return), spawn avTerminal)`

Comment: OOps My Bad: I am sorry. i missed it.  well in that case i can only guess the urxvtc is not found or something. Nick: can you confirm the urxvtc is installed?

Answer (score 0):

The windows key is your mod now.

The relevent line is :

```
 modMask               = mod4Mask
```